Group element of group algebra
For a prime $p$, let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and $F_{p}$ the field with $p$ elements.
Let $A=\{a\in F_{p}G \mid a^{\sum_{x\in G}x}\neq 0\}$, where $F_pG$ is the group algebra of $G$ over $F_p$ and $a^{\sum_{x\in G}x} := \sum_{x\in G}x^{-1}ax$ is conjugation. Write $A\cong H\times Z_{p-1}$, where $H$ is a finite $p$-group.
My question is: do we have $\mathrm{exp}(H)=p^{n}$ if $\exp(G)=p^n$ (where $\mathrm{exp}$ denotes the exponent)?

The answer is no. Your $A$ is the group of units of $F_pG$, and $H$ is the group of units of the form $1+x$ where $x$ is in the radical of $F_pG$. Now let $G$ be an extraspecial group of order $27$ and exponent $3$, $$G=\langle g,h,z\mid g^3=h^3=z^3=1,[g,h]=z,[g,z]=[h,z]=1\rangle.$$ Let $x=(g-1)+(h-1)=g+h-2$. Then $x^3$ is not zero, so $(1+x)^3$ is not the identity in $F_3G$.
Edit: Interestingly, the group algebra in this case has an easy presentation. If we let $a=g-1$, $b=h-1$, $c=ab-ba$, then the group algebra has presentation $a^3=0$, $b^3=0$, $[a,b]=c$, $[a,c]=cbc$, $[b,c]=-cac$. These relations imply that $c^3$ is $0$, but $(a+b)^3$ isn't. For more information, please see my paper with Kessar and Linckelmann, "Structure of blocks with normal defect and abelian $p'$ inertial quotient".
Edit 2: I seem to have misread the question to make it more interesting than it really is. I interpreted $a^{\sum_{x\in G}x}$ as $a.\scriptstyle\sum_{x\in G}x$. If you interpret it as $\sum_{x\in G}x^{-1}ax$ then for $G$ non-trivial $A$ is empty, because $G$ has a non-trivial centre, so everything gets counted $p$ times and the sum is zero.
